# Error in Ingeres E_SC0520_SCS_BAD_DBV SCS_INPUT invalid DBV detected:

Tags: database, ingres

Please need help! Issuing this problem for couple days cannot understand and find any useful information on how to resolve it 
I am getting this error when I am trying to run procedure with call from php

```
E_AD2005_BAD_DTLEN ADF routine found DB_DATA_VALUE with an invalid length.
E_SC0520_SCS_BAD_DBV SCS_INPUT invalid DBV detected: db_datatype = -20, db_length = 1, db_prec = 0.
E_SC021C_SCS_INPUT_ERROR SCS_INPUT internal error.
```

any idea how to resolve it and what does it mean ? 
also, strange thing i am getting this error only if I do call from php , if I am calling this procedure from Visual DBA its running perfectly with no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of one of your parameters is inconsistent with the declaration in the procedure..

Remember php by default does not define its variables until you put something in it so if you are dealing with a string and it has numeric values php will see that as a numeric variable ..

If in doubt cast your variables (string) $variable_name.